# Adding a "title" field to video thumbnails in the Video Module

Tags: 7, entities, files

I would like to attach a textfield field to the video field. How can I go about doing that programmatically?

How do you attach a field of a field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(), there is no any built-in option to do that.

You can also use the [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to create a new field collection with a text field, and the video field.

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) to add a `#process` function to the widget. This is what the Image field does in [image_field_widget_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_form/7), by adding [image_field_widget_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_process/7) as `#process` function.

```
// Add all extra functionality provided by the image widget.
$elements[$delta]['#process'][] = 'image_field_widget_process';
```

If you need to save the content of the form field you add, and the field doesn't provide a database field to save it, there is nothing much you can do, until [No hook_field_schema_alter()](http://drupal.org/node/691932) gets implemented for Drupal 7 too.